# customized Qprogressbar in python qt

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7

is it possible to develop a multicoloured progressbar? tried with gradient color but did not work.
like the below progressbar using pyqt5.

[image]

[image]

code:

```
QProgressBar{
font: 2pt "Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold";
padding: 0px;
border:None;    
color: qlineargradient( x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.181818 rgba(0, 74, 134, 255), stop:0.392045 rgba(0, 104, 181, 255), stop:0.619318 rgba(0, 163, 246, 255), stop:0.6875 rgba(0, 199, 253, 255));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked by making color as background color.
and added qprogressbar::chunk

```
QProgressBar{
font: 2pt "Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold";
padding: 0px;
border:None;    
}
QProgressBar::chunk{
background-color: qlineargradient( x0: 0, x2: 1, 
stop:0 rgba(0, 74, 134, 255),stop:0.1 rgba(0, 74, 134, 255),
 stop:0.11 rgba(0, 104, 181, 255), stop:0.25 rgba(0, 104, 181, 255), 
stop:0.26 rgba(0, 163, 246, 255), stop:0.5 rgba(0, 163, 246, 255), 
stop:0.51 rgba(0, 199, 253, 255),stop:1 rgba(0, 199, 253, 255));
}
```

Comment: Note that sometimes Qt is a bit annoying with syntaxes, so there should not be a space after the open parenthesis (and it should be `x1`, not `x0`).